# Query performance fluctuation

Tags: nhibernate

i'm running queries from NHibernate and have my profiler set up to trace any slow queries, there are a few which seem to take 10+ seconds in my profiler mainly:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT top 50 this_.Debiteur_ID as Debiteur1_44_6_, this_.Debiteurnaam as Debiteur2_44_6_, this_.Debiteurnummer as Debiteur3_44_6_, this_.IsBedrijf_NeeJa as 
IsBedrijf4_44_6_, this_.Bedrijfsnaam as Bedrijfs5_44_6_, this_.Achternaam as Achternaam44_6_, this_.Tussenvoegsel as Tussenvo7_44_6_, this_.Voorletters as Voorlett8_44_6_, 
this_.Geboortedatum as Geboorte9_44_6_, this_.Titel_ID as Titel10_44_6_, this_.ManVrouw as ManVrouw44_6_, this_.Entiteit_ID as Entiteit12_44_6_, this_.Rechtsvorm_ID as Rechtsvorm13_44_6_, 
this_.Account_ID as Account14_44_6_, this_.Vestiging_Postcode as Vestiging15_44_6_, this_.Vestiging_Adres as Vestiging16_44_6_, this_.Vestiging_Plaats as Vestiging17_44_6_, 
this_.Vestiging_Huisnummer as Vestiging18_44_6_, this_.Vestiging_Land_ID as Vestiging19_44_6_, this_.Correspondentie_Postcode as Corresp20_44_6_, this_.Correspondentie_Adres as 
Corresp21_44_6_, this_.Correspondentie_Plaats as Corresp22_44_6_, this_.Correspondentie_Huisnummer as Corresp23_44_6_, this_.Correspondentie_Land_ID as Corresp24_44_6_, this_.Telefoonnummer as Telefoo25_44_6_, this_.Email as Email44_6_, this_.Mobiel as Mobiel44_6_, title3_.Titel_ID as Titel1_65_0_, title3_.Omschrijving as Omschrij2_65_0_, gender4_.Geslacht_ID as Geslacht1_30_1_, gender4_.Omschrijving as Omschrij2_30_1_, typeofcomp5_.Rechtsvorm_ID as Rechtsvorm1_8_2_, typeofcomp5_.Omschrijving as Omschrij2_8_2_, country6_.Land_ID as Land1_7_3_, country6_.Omschrijving as Omschrij2_7_3_, country6_.ISO as ISO7_3_, country6_.ISO_3166_a3 as ISO4_7_3_, country7_.Land_ID as Land1_7_4_, country7_.Omschrijving as Omschrij2_7_4_, country7_.ISO as ISO7_4_, country7_.ISO_3166_a3 as ISO4_7_4_, debtorreac1_.Debiteur_ID as Debiteur1_3_5_, debtorreac1_.DateOfOldestReaction as DateOfOl2_3_5_, debtorreac1_.TotalAmountOfReactions as TotalAmo3_3_5_, debtorreac1_.AmountOfResolvedReactions as AmountOf4_3_5_, debtorreac1_.AmountOfUnresolvedReactions as AmountOf5_3_5_, debtorreac1_.TotalOpenAmount as TotalOpe6_3_5_, debtorreac1_.UnresolvedOpenAmount as Unresolv7_3_5_, debtorreac1_.ResolvedOpenAmount as Resolved8_3_5_ FROM tbl_Debiteur this_ left outer join tbl_Titel title3_ on this_.Titel_ID=title3_.Titel_ID left outer join tbl_Geslacht gender4_ on this_.ManVrouw=gender4_.Geslacht_ID left outer join tbl_Rechtsvorm typeofcomp5_ on this_.Rechtsvorm_ID=typeofcomp5_.Rechtsvorm_ID left outer join tbl_Land country6_ on this_.Vestiging_Land_ID=country6_.Land_ID left outer join tbl_Land country7_ on this_.Correspondentie_Land_ID=country7_.Land_ID left outer join vw_DebtorReactionDetails debtorreac1_ on this_.Debiteur_ID=debtorreac1_.Debiteur_ID WHERE this_.Entiteit_ID = @p0 and debtorreac1_.AmountOfUnresolvedReactions > @p1 ORDER BY this_.Debiteur_ID asc',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=1104,@p1=0
```

When i run the exact same query i just pasted here like this so including the parameters and everything the query takes less then a second.

I have no idea why this is happening but performance as it is right now simply isn't going to work out.

Greetings.

Comment: What profiler are you using?  Have you run a performance test of this query using ADO.NET?  It's not clear from the information you've provided where the problem is originating.

Comment: Could it have something to do with transactions? perhaps you are using something like serializable in Nhibernate?

Comment: Profiler i'm using is just the SQL Server Profiler, nothing special there. I've not run specific performance tests on this query. The 2nd time i run the query is in SQL Management studio. In MSQL MS the query runs in less then a second but from NHibernate it's slow as heck.

I'm not sure what Serializable in NHibernate is exactly. I do know this query is run outside of a transaction since nothing is beeing updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since i visited this topic, we tweaked the query some, added some more indexes but more importantly now run on a more powerfull server.

This all said i believe the problem i was running into was one of Parameter sniffing:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/

The issue(s) for now atleast are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the query itself is the culprit?
I'm pretty sure that its not the execution of the query that is slow but the process of hydrating the according mapped entities and especially considering collections  and/or many-to-one associations and their collection when you have disabled lazy loading.

first check your mappings if you have set eager fetching, 
try setting

```
<property name="max_fetch_depth">1</property>
```

in your NH config just to limit automatic eager fetching (remember to remove/change the value afterwards)